# How to construct WebAppContext without web.xml file in jetty?

Tags: embedded-jetty

WebAppContext has method setWar(String war). If you don't want to use war file, then you can pass the web.xml by calling setDescriptor(String descriptor) method.

My need is to even avoid web.xml.
Is it possible?

I have a class which implements the service. Its annotated with '@WebService(endpointInterface = "someServiceInterface")'.

How can I map the WebAppContext to the this class?

Answer (score 0):

If the need is to avoid web.xml, then there is no need to set the WebAppContext and no need of jetty server. 
One can just use following method to publish the web service on desired end-point using jax-ws.

Endpoint publish(String address, Object implementor) from javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.

Comment: Basically I had posted wrong question. The actual question could have been - how to publish web service without web.xml with or without jetty server.